# How to randomly play a sound file from a directory using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to have windows run this vbs file at the start of windows so that the computer can greet me with phrases that I've made and saved as wav files.

I already have one vbs file where it plays a sound file but I want it to randomly pick one from a specific directory so that it doesn't get old hearing the same thing over and over again, plus add a surprise factor because I don't know which one it'll use each time I start the computer.

```
Dim oPlayer
Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")

' Play audio
oPlayer.URL = "C:\Users\david\OneDrive\Desktop\GLaDOS 
wav\Edited\hello_david_youre_back_i_see.wav"
oPlayer.controls.play 
While oPlayer.playState <> 1 ' 1 = Stopped
WScript.Sleep 100
Wend

' Release the audio file
oPlayer.close
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim oFolderItems
Dim oFolderItem
Dim aFiles

Set oFolderItems = CreateObject("Shell.Application").NameSpace("C:\Users\david\OneDrive\Desktop\GLaDOSwav\Edited").Items
oFolderItems.Filter 64 + 128, "*.wav"
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each oFolderItem In oFolderItems
        .Item(.Count) = oFolderItem.Path
    Next
    aFiles = .Items
End With
Randomize
With CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
    .URL = aFiles(Int(Rnd * UBound(aFiles) + 1))
    .controls.play 
    Do While .playState <> 1
        WScript.Sleep 100
    Loop
    .close
End With
```

Comment: what is the equivalent for `WMPlayer.OCX` in VBA?